# __webpack_require__(...) is not a function after adding a CSS to Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I have a working angular 2 website, using webpack to pack the resources. This pack is pretty much(for now) what I generated with `dotnet new angular`command.

I already added some ressources to be packed, and they worked fine.

But now I added a CSS file of a icon library in my entry-vendor list of `webpack.config.vendor.js`:

```
entry: {
    vendor: [
        //[...all others...]
        'icon-sets/icons/solid-icons/premium-solid-icons.min.css', 
    ]
},
```

I ran webpack:
`webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`(no errors), I build and start the website, then I directly get an error:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function at Object.<anonymous> 
(E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:380:50) at __webpack_require__ (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) 
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1636:22) 
at __webpack_require__ (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) 
at Object.c (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:256:18) 
at __webpack_require__ (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) 
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:153:23) 
at __webpack_require__ (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) 
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:349:20) 
at __webpack_require__ (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30) 
at E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:66:18 
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\My\Project\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:69:10) 
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10) 
at Module.load (module.js:488:32) Current directory is: E:\My\Project
```

My understanding is that .Net tries to pre-render some stuffs and fails due to webpack, but no idea why and how to fix it.

Any idea?